# Firebase Auth Couldn't Verify Domain

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a Firebase account, and I want to tailor the email address from which verification emails are sent. I follow the instructions.

[image]

I have a domain registered with 1&1 and set up as instructed.

[image]

But after about 2 days, I get the following.

[image]

Please can anyone advise.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the trailing space on your TXT record?

```
$ dig txt thewhozoo.com

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> txt thewhozoo.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 59407
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;thewhozoo.com.         IN  TXT

;; ANSWER SECTION:
thewhozoo.com.      3600    IN  TXT "firebase=thewhozoo-143913 "
thewhozoo.com.      3600    IN  TXT "v=spf1 include:_spf.firebasemail.com ~all "

;; Query time: 45 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.1.1#53(192.168.1.1)
;; WHEN: Thu Jun  8 23:49:07 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 125
```

Comment: Thanks Dominic. That seems to have been the issue. I managed to verify the changes now.

Comment: No bounty award?

Comment: Hi Dominic, sorry, I thought it got assigned automatically to the correct answer. I think you should have it now.

Comment: Cheers Richard - I noticed the same thing and thought it was automatic myself!

Answer (score 38):

I also was unable to verify my custom domain for the auth templates.

My solution was to remove my custom domain from the host name in the DNS records needed for the verification.

Example:

> TXT record: from **contoso.com** to **@**
>
> CNAME record: from **firebase._domainkey.contoso.com** to **firebase._domainkey**

*Note: My domain is hosted by Godaddy.com*

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it for me too. They're giving bad instructions on Firebase, apparently..

Comment: Thanks for this it worked after struggling for more than 72 hrs. Firebase really need to fix this

Comment: Thanks! This is also help me, agree with both comments too.

Comment: After months trying everything I just removed my domain name from firebase._domainkey and it finally worked!. I use Google Domains, so I thought that their instruction would at least work with their own domain system, but no, it didn't. They should updated Firebase domain verification.

Answer (score 11):

For those using Cloudflare. Make sure you don't have DNS flattening activated in the CNAME.

[image]

Comment: This worked for me! Just to confirm for those in the future, you need to make it so Cloudflare looks like the picture in this answer.

Comment: It should be good to revert it back after too :) I believe firebase just needs to detect it first

Comment: The UI has changed slightly since this was posted but the same principle applies. Proxy status should be set to "DNS Only" instead of the default value "Proxied". This worked for me.

Comment: can confirm it works, and for anyone in doubt, on cloudflare you *do not need* to use @ as domain name

Comment: Are there any security concerns by turning this off?